# Items in The "New" Context Menu is Missing Only on Normal Users

Tags: windows, active-directory, context-menu

A computer which is running Windows server 2018 sp2 is part of the AD domain. However, any domain users, local users and local administrator, except the domain administrator, can't create any new items by right-clicking on the blank area and select new on their desktops and folders. Because it's empty under the new context menu.

[image]
I tried to restore the registry followed by this [link](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-missing-new-menuitem-in-desktop-and-explorer-context-menu/), and edit GPO by this [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-right-click-context-menus-windows-explorer)

None of them worked. I even tried to create the registry items which were described by the first link in the GPO but doesn't work.

Any other methods to address this issue?

Comment: Please describe a specific scenario you are trying to do. It sounds like you are mixing up explorer context menus with Active Directory Users & Computers context menus. Since you tagged this as active-directory, I can only assume you are trying to create an object within Active Directory using an account that has not been granted permissions to do so.

Comment: I was trying to restore the New context menu. As I described, it only showed in in Domain Administrator account, so I am wondering why other users can't get the menu.

Comment: Because those other users do not belong to a security group which has create/delete permission to child objects of the OU. You need to research Active Directory delegations.

Comment: You say "right-clicking on the blank area" - *what* blank area?  On the desktop?  Inside Active Directory Users & Computers?  In an Explorer window?  If so, what folder?  Without more information, there's no way for us to tell what if anything has gone wrong.  If you're not sure how to describe what you're trying to do, please post a screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Harry, I have updated my question, thanks for that

Comment: And does this happen on every folder, even, e.g., the user's own Documents folder?

Comment: Yes, it happens on every folder.